# How can I rework my MySQL password so that I can rake db: create on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, passwords, root

I've very much so tried it all.

when I db:rake create, I get the following:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). 
Please provide the root password for your mysql installation
>
rake aborted!

There is no password set.  And I've searched all day on stackoverflow and on google.
I've even set a password for it and tried that out.

Yes, I've been to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix

But when I followed the instructions to reset the password, terminal and myself are unable to locate the .pid file!

I've tried using the mysqld_safe with --skip-grant-tables option and wound up with this:

110821 23:32:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
rm: /tmp/mysql.sock: Permission denied
110821 23:32:24 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Tony-Ngs-MacBook-Air.local.pid ended

Comment: Can you confirm that you can connect to your server by simple mysql cli? With "--user=root" option, just as Rails would connect? If no, then I would stop here and solve this problem, probably something with MySQL configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you just need to add the password in your database.yml file. That's an error that's displayed when the client connecting to mysql didn't specify a password, not a configuration issue with the server (although it does appear that way with the phrasing).

If you need to set your password in MySQL, you do it with a grant option:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'railsuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: I'm getting this as a response @Doug Kress:
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'railsuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to log into mysql as a user with privileges. In some systems, by default, that just means logging in as root before running mysql.