# Just installed MySQL. Unable to use any commands. Unknown root password

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried following this post:
[How can I rework my MySQL password so that I can rake db: create on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143891/how-can-i-rework-my-mysql-password-so-that-i-can-rake-db-create-on-rails)

As it most closely addresses my problem except the answers aren't specific/detailed enough i.e. I am a huge newbie and don't know what commands to run.

This is my problem:
:~/myapp$ rake db:create

Access denied for user 'todallyrad'@'localhost' (using password: YES)Please provide the root password for your mysql installation.

I don't know the root password or how to change it. I got started trying to follow this:
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04
But got stuck at the very end. I tried doing the suggested change of the database.yml file using VIM but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default root password for MySQL is no password. Either edit your database.yml file, enter `root` as user, leave `password` blank. Or use mysql command line console to create a user with password. And add a root password.

Comment: I tried editing the database.yml file with VIM with no luck. Getting this error still: Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", "database"=>"myapp_test"}

Answer (score 0):

You may change your root password as per below:

STOP mysql service

> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
>
> sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &

Login into mysql DB using root user

> mysql -u root mysql

Set password for your root user

> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('**YOURPASSWORD**') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;

Comment: "sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &" produces this error: $ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 3427
todallyrad@todallyrad-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ 140630  2:10:26 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. Also, "mysql -u root mysql" produces this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

use `root` as username and leave `password` blank for the first time and then when you are log in, you can add account for database connection.